# How to label an array correctly?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table in my Database where my script is storing its values.
I want to achieve the following, if a "description" already exists, I want it to show up once, but count up all the duplicate rows. The following code does exactly what I want, but I want to mark it with a "label" and the value with a "y"
Currently I have the following code:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            foreach($result as $row){
            $dataPoints[$row['description']] += $row['hours'];
            }
            print_r($dataPoints);       
        }
    }
```

Output is:

```
Array ( [Mail] => 35)
```

But I want the dataPoints array to show up as:

```
Array ( [label] => Mail [y] => 35 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line: `$dataPoints[$row['description']] += $row['hours'];`

to:

```
$dataPoint['label'] = $row['description'];
$dataPoint['y'] += $row['hours'];
```

To use the `+=` operator you should make sure that `$dataPoint['y']` has a value, otherwise a warning is shown, like `Warning: Undefined array key "y"`

EDIT, to only count the records where `description` equals `Mail`:

```
IF ($row['description')=='Mail') {
   $dataPoint['label'] = $row['description'];
   $dataPoint['y'] += $row['hours'];
}
```

Comment: This is not working, Output is: Array ( [label] => Mail [y] => 194.75 ) the 194.75 is the total of all hours combined in the table. I want it to show only the total of all rows where "description" equals "Mail"

Comment: Updated with the extra info you gave.